# Receiving Gradle connection time out even though using local distribution

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build this project from Google - https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa

In my Android Studio, I have the setting "Use local Gradle distribution" and the folder is gradle 5.5.1 that I have downloaded

When I try to sync the files, it runs for a few minutes and then I get an error

> ERROR: Connection timed out: connect

and the following in the log

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1634)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1606)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.execute(CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.java:45)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.execute(CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.resolveClassPath(DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.getScriptClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:80)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:204)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:106)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1.
Required by:
    project :
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.5.1/gradle-5.5.1.pom'.
```

I added `mavenLocal()` to my `build.gradle` file - what is trying to get this file?

I am behind a firewall/proxy that I have no access to change on my machine (hence why I downloaded Gradle rather than getting it from a repo)

I cannot figure out what is trying to get this file

Comment: It's obvious the error is coming from here: `Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1` . Try downgrading it, then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: @DevMike01I have downloaded the POM file for 3.4.2 (which matches my Android Studio version) - where do I place the POM file so that it can be referenced rather than being searched for online?

Comment: You don't need a POM file... Goto your Gradle file in your project's level and replace the gradle classpath in question with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`.